# PostGIS raster write support in R

Tags: postgis, raster, r, rgdal

I want to push/write some generated raster layers to my postgres database directly in R. In theory this could be supported by the `rgdal` package, but sadly it isn't. In the latest version only copy, but not write is supported (Can be queried by `gdalDrivers()` ).

Earlier this year it was announced that there might be a coding project as part of the google summer of code competition
[Link](http://tinyurl.com/kjxelyf)

Does anyone know what has happened there and if write via `writeGDAL` is now possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [GDAL PostGIS Raster driver documentation](http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/frmts_wtkraster.html), last updated February 2014:

> write support to GDAL PostGIS Raster driver is under development

The best available tool is still [raster2pgsql](http://postgis.refractions.net/docs/using_raster.xml.html#RT_Raster_Loader) on a local GeoTIFF file.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try the package 'RpostgreSQL'.

I'm not sure, if it will allow you to write spatial data to PostGresql, but you can try.